# Dynamic class loading and application context creation Spring application migration to Quarkus

Tags: spring-boot, migration, quarkus, applicationcontext

I'm new to Quarkus and I'm analysing the migration viability of a peculiar "Spring Boot" application.

The application is a "rules engine" used by the company's own CRM in order to provide a Wizard to sales and quoting processes; making all the business, elegibility and product structure complexity transparent to the CRM application.

To accomplish that, the CORE of the application counts with several "rules bases" which can configured/programed based on Java, Drools and other languages/definitions.

When this application starts, it detects all previously compiled/stored bases and deserializes them.
But, if a base is not found among the serialized ones, it compiles and stores it to avoid this high consuming step next time.

The application allows also to reprocess a specific base "on the fly" (at the end of the reprocessing fase, the current version of the "rules base" is replaced by the one that was just compiled).

The problem I'm facing is regarding the dynamic loading of the bases which involves, among other this, the dynamic creation of application context and class loading like on code snippet below:

```
public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext processPackages(
    Set< String > packages,
    ClassLoader loader,
    String configName,
    boolean doRefresh ) {

    if ( applicationContext != null && packages != null ) {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.setParent( applicationContext );
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.setClassLoader( loader );
        RulesEngineContext context = new RulesEngineContext( configName, null );

        RulesEngineContextHolder.set( context );
        packages.add( GLOBAL_BEAN_CONFIGURATOR );

        for ( String pkg : packages ) {
            annotationConfigApplicationContext.scan( pkg );
        }

        if ( doRefresh ) {
            annotationConfigApplicationContext.refresh();
        }

        return annotationConfigApplicationContext;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The only possibility I could imagine until now to migrate this application to Quarkus will demand a considerable refactoring with the loss of "on the fly" reprocessing of "rules bases" and the creation of a Quarkus extension to load and index all dependencies demanded by all "rules bases" before startup.

Does anyone could help me out with any ideas how to accomplish the migration of such application?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Things like this are not supported in Quarkus.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @geoand! I was suspecting that some features of this application wouldn't allow it to be migrated to Quarkus and one of the most challenging was regarding the dynamic loading and compilation of the "rules bases", but I was hopping that [this](https://quarkus.io/blog/solving-problems-with-custom-extensions/) post could point out a solution to the problem. Nevertheless, I believe your answer put an end to the matter. Thanks again!